# How to programmatically logout from websphere portal 8.5 application using Java code?

Tags: java, websphere-portal

I have a websphere portal application running very well. The current logout command is available in default theme. 
I wanted to know how to logout the portal from java/spring source code? Can we call the same command method e.g. "logout" from server side java code?
I have functionality of change password. After change password, I want to logout user.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the list of items which you need to try from your portlet

```
final PortletStateManager mgr = getPortletStateManager(request, response);
urlFactory = mgr.getURLFactory();
url = urlFactory.newURL(com.ibm.portal.state.Constants.EMPTY_COPY); //If no state from the current request to be preserved
LogoutActionAccessorFactory logoutFct = mgr.getAccessorFactory(LogoutActionAccessorFactory.class);
LogoutActionAccessorController logoutCtrl = logoutFct.newLogoutActionController(url.getState());logoutCtrl.dispose();
finalUrl = url.writeDispose(new StringWriter()).toString();
```

The same can be done from a Servlet also. You will see corresponding AccessorFactory and AccessorController in the portal documentation.

**EDITED**

PortletStateManager is obtained from PortletStateManagerService which again is obtained from PortletServiceHome using a JNDI lookup.

The right way to find out this is by going through the Java docs of Portal. Refer the interface `PortletStateManagerService`. The comment section clearly tells how to get it.

You can fine the Java docs of Portal here `<portal-install-root>\WebSphere\PortalServer\doc\Javadoc\spi_docs`

Comment: Sorry I am new to portlet. Can I ask few question? 1. What is the implementation of getPortletStateManager(request, response) 2. what are class name for urlFactory, url & finalUrl Variables.

Comment: You can find the class names of these, by looking at the return values of the method that uses it. Make use of the Java docs which is shared in the answer. That's the best way to explore it.